# Use logical deduction to show that the following propositions are unconditionally true

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, sequent-calculus

These two questions:

1) $P \to ((Q \lor R) \to P)$

and

2) $(P \to (Q \to R)) \to ( P \land Q \to R)$

It'd be really helpful if you could answer these for. I managed to answer the ones that give me a predetermined value of True or False for P Q R, but I don't know how to answer these using logical deduction.

Thank you if you try!

Comment: What are the "bars" ? Please use \land ($\land$) for "and" and \lor ($\lor$) for "or".

Comment: Use Truth table.

Comment: For 2), see [Exportation (logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)).

Comment: For 1): if properly written, is an [axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_1._Simple_axiom_system) of propositional calculus.

Comment: Alternatively, for 1) you can use [Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) and [logical equivalences](http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf).

Comment: @Makerz123 Do you have to use a specific method? Can you use equivalences? Or a truth-table? Or do you have to use rules of inference? (sounds like the latter, since you talk about 'logical deduction' ...)  If the latter, what rules are given to you?

Comment: @Makerz123 Ah, ok, so you have to use a sequent system style derivation, that helps!  Still, even those sequent systems can be defined differently ... could you also post the specific rules for the system as defined in your text? (maybe they are nicely  organized on one page at the end of the chapter or in an appendix?)

Comment: @Makerz123 OK, that last problem about perceptron requires a whole separate post; let's not muddy the waters here!  Now, these sequent systems proofs are far from being the most intuitive proof systems, so I can understand you're struggling with these ... did you go over some examples at least?

Comment: @Makerz123 I;m familiar with the perceptron learning algorithm, sure, though I'm a little fuzzy on that 'hard activation threshold' ... I assume it has something to do with the weight vector being of size 3 rather than 2; seems like the third 'input' is held at a constant 1 or -1? Anyway, if you post that, you'll get the whole community thinking for you, not just me! :)  Now, the the logical deductions though: for the first one: to show that $P \rightarrow ((Q \lor R) \rightarrow P)$ is unconditionally true, you have to show that $\vdash P \rightarrow ((Q \lor R) \rightarrow P)$ ...

Comment: @Makerz123 Well, since you want $\vdash P \rightarrow ((Q \lor R) \rightarrow P)$, and since the main connective of that statement is a $\rightarrow$, what rule do you think you'd need to get that statement?

Comment: @Makerz123 Right, but now we're going to do it with the rules. OK, so you *want* a $\rightarrow$ ... and we *get* s $\rightarrow$ through $\rightarrow$ Right. Given that rule, this means we want to go from $P \vdash (Q \lor R) \rightarrow P$ to $\vdash P \rightarrow ((Q \lor R) \rightarrow P)$ as our last step in the derivation  or 'proof tree' (That is, we set $\varphi$ to $P$, $\chi$ to $(Q \lor R) \rightarrow P$, and both $\Delta$ to $\Gamma$ to the emptyset.  Do you see how that works?  And now that we want $P \vdash (Q \lor R) \rightarrow P$, how do you think we can get that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76174/discussion-on-question-by-makerz123-use-logical-deduction-to-show-that-the-follo).

Comment: Please do not edit the question away after you get an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof for the first one:

\begin{align}
\cfrac{
\cfrac{
\cfrac{\{ P, Q \lor R \} \cap \{ P \} \not = \emptyset}{P, Q \lor R \vdash P} \text{Assm}
}
{P \vdash (Q \lor R) \rightarrow P}\rightarrow \text {Right}}
{\vdash P \rightarrow ((Q \lor R) \rightarrow P)}\rightarrow \text {Right}
\end{align}

The key is to start at the bottom, and work your way back. Keep asking: given that my goal is ...., what rule allows me to get ...?

Comment: @Makerz123 Yes, because it shows $\vdash P \rightarrow ((Q \lor R) \rightarrow P)$, i.e. $P \rightarrow ((Q \lor R) \rightarrow P)$ follows from 'nothing', i.e. is unconditionally true.

Comment: @Makerz123 Well, that first one was just an easy one ... that second one is indeed a bit harder. The implication in between is not a problem: you just keep introducing them with the $\rightarrow$ Right rule. But the conditionals in the antecedent will make that proof a little more complicated. Again, though, the key is to work back from your goal.

Comment: @Makerz123 Can you make a start with that one? ... again, working backwards form the goal ...

Comment: @Makerz123 No. You want to go from $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R) \vdash (P \land Q) \rightarrow R$ to $\vdash (P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)) \rightarrow ((P \land Q) \rightarrow R)$ because that $\rightarrow$ in the middle is the main connective, not the one right after the first $P$.

Comment: @Makerz123 I see you got a lot of help from Graham ... and in fact Graham pretty much finished that whole proof now!

Comment: @Makerz123 It's because you still have a conditional on the left side in $Q \rightarrow R, P, Q \vdash R$ ... so you need to use a $\rightarrow $ Left rule to split that.  And what you need to point out is that $\{ P, Q \} \cap \{ Q, R \} = \{ Q \} \not = \emptyset$ and that $\{ P, Q, R \} \cap \{ R \} = \{R \} \not = \emptyset$.

Comment: @Makerz123 Also, make sure to accept Graham's answer by clicking on the check mark next to it!

Comment: @Makerz123 Yes, all correct!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

1) $P,Q \vdash P$ --- axiom

2) $P,R \vdash P$ --- axiom

3) $P,Q \lor R \vdash P$ --- ($\lor\text{Left }$) from 1) and 2)

4) $P \vdash (Q \lor R) \to P$ --- ($\to \text{Right}$)

> 5) $\vdash P \to ((Q \lor R) \to P)$ --- ($\to \text{Right}$).

Comment: @Makerz123  Make two assumptions, argue a derivation for $R$, then use conditional introduction twice.